# Protecting software code and IP freelancers and outsourcing

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualhost, virtualization

While hiring freelancers to work on a software project, what is the way to enable them to work on the project but project software IP. If we provide them access to the full code, the developer can easily download the entire code to the local computer.

Comment: You sign contracts for that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: It is eseential question for expansion of any company. It is a real cocnern for us as we try to scale. Will really appreciate help from the community

Comment: Nobody is saying this isn't an interesting question, it's just not about programming. Try it at the Software Engineering or Workplace Stack Exchange, *if* after reading their help center it seems to be on-topic on any of those.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to build the project as separate libraries (binaries), assuming you're not working with non-compilable (scripts, python, JS etc) languages.
Not being able to trust your developers, however, should be a warning of much higher risk for your project...

Comment: Thanks Kheldar. Once a company starts hiring 10 to 15 developers, it is hard to keep tabs on what everyone is doing. IP is a known issue with hiring developers in emerging markets

Comment: Its a pity the question got closed without understanding the situation

Comment: It's not programming per-se. It's software engineering, and you probably should move it on the relevant stack exchange site (and remove it from here).